# Why is the visited link color not changing when I give the absolute link in anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I have made a link in html using anchor tag. I have defined an unvisited color and a visited color for the link in css as follows :

```
#menu{
  color:#000000;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;    
}

#menu a:link{color:blue;}
#menu a:visited{color:red;}
```

HTML code:

```
<div align = " right" id="menu">
<a  href="D:\MyFolder\ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

When I give the relative address in "href" attribute of anchor tag, everything is working fine.

e.g.  `href = "ContactUs.html"`  --since they are in same folder

But when I give the absolute address in `href` attribute of anchor tag, the color is not changing from "blue" to "red" on visiting the page. It remains "blue" only.

e.g.  href = "D:\MyFolder\ContactUs.html"

Kindly explain why is it so ?

Comment: can you post the code of your menu?

Comment: Just aside why you will need to use that kind of absolute path ? Always use relative

Comment: But with the absolute link also I am able to go to the other page. Only the link color is not changing after visiting the page

Comment: I'd say that link href will show up in the history of the browser something like file://d blah blah. If you put absolute links like that on your page you're going to have to change every single one of them if you make the site live or change the location of the site.

Comment: @  Top Questions, I have posted the code of menu

Comment: i think he means the htrml code....

Comment: @Billy here is the html code

Comment: have a look in your browser history at the address when you have visited one of these links, what does it say ? I would definately think about using relative links, you'll never be able to move the page without recoding.

Comment: you forgot the "#" in front of "menu a" you need to reference the id like this: "#menu a:visited{.."

Comment: @Billy I am not able to find any history about this page in the browser

Comment: @ BrendanMullins sorry I forgot to copy here but I have written it in the code

Comment: what, no history of any pages. when you click the link and go to the page then click once in the address bar and  highlight the url in it, what does that say.

Comment: @Billy It is giving the address as "D:\MyFolder\ContactUs.html"

Comment: are you sure the slashes are not the other way ....D:/MyFolder/ContactUs.html

Comment: @Danko kindly explain why can't I give an absolute path like this?

Comment: @user4449595 when you upload the site that kind of paths are just invalid as doesn't exist on the host always use relative that way you can acces all elements always. with just the folder structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the css class is for `visited` not `clicked`.

So when you click on `<a  href="D:\MyFolder\ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>` and the browser automatically detects that it is a file, it redirects to `file:///d:/MyFolder/ContactUs.html` and marks that as visited, not the path you are specifying.

So as said, either change your links to have `file:///` in front, or use relative links (which makes more sense)

Answer (score 3):

I've tested with links in two variants:
1 `href="D:\path\file.html"`
2 `href="file:///d:/path/file.html"`

Chrome styles the link as `:visited` in both cases. Firefox and MSIE only highlight the `file:///` link as visited.

If the page is hosted from a http server the link is not marked as visited in MSIE in neither case. Firefox and Chrome style the `file:` link as visited, but only Firefox  allows you to follow a link, but the unstyled(!) one (with `D:\`, not with `file:`).

So you should use `<a href="file:///d:/MyFolder/ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>` to make it work in all browsers as long as both pages are opened as a local file. (But really you should use relative links).