# Using CSS visited property for href to a file

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML of 2 anchor tags, one to a file and one to google

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/foobar.csv">
    http://example.com/files/foobar.csv
</a>
<a href="http://google.com">
    Google
</a>
```

I also have this CSS to make visited anchor tags red.

```
a:visited {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

When I click on the google link, the link turns red as expected because I have visited it.

When I click on the file however, the link does not turn red.

So it seems file paths work differently than url paths.

**How can I get the visited property working on anchor tags with href to a file**

Comment: Interesting... a catch all would be to add a class on clicking but that's JS not strictly just css

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Also, visited css is persistent on a page reload. Anything I do with javascript will need cookies or something similar for the same behavior.

Comment: @Goose Yeah, it's def not ideal if you want it persisted - is there a specific reason why it's important to you? If you can share that it might shed some light on a possible alternative solution if that's an option to you

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Business application, provide a list of files for download, would be useful for users to see which files they have already downloaded, would prefer a simple solution, this is nothing mission critical. Even if there is a work around in my instance, I'd like to know if this is possible and why it doesn't work the same, just for knowledge sake.

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a security concern why that is happening.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Not sure how but possible. Can you give an example where it could be a privacy or security concern in a way visited on non files is not?

Comment: @Goose I just read it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193285/why-is-the-visited-link-color-not-changing-when-i-give-the-absolute-link-in-anch. A more direct link is found here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: Or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331688/why-doesnt-this-avisited-css-style-work

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Fairly relevant questions. I saw the first one before asking, but it only applies to local file system paths to files, not web paths to files, second is interesting, but the answer and it's link https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/ doesn't mention or address the behavior I'm seeing and reading it, don't see anything that suggests that would be the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the visited link color not changing when I give the absolute link in anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193285/why-is-the-visited-link-color-not-changing-when-i-give-the-absolute-link-in-anch)

Comment: @Liz https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers "If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.". I think you should mark the other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try to insert the URL directly in Browser History.

You can do something like:

HTML:

```js
$(".file-link").click( function () {
  $(this).attr("href");
  var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
  window.history.pushState({ title: "Services" }, "foobar.csv", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/files/foobar.csv" class="file-link">
    http://example.com/files/foobar.csv
</a>
<a href="http://google.com">
    Google
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer is also listed here: [text-decoration not working for visited state link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031032/text-decoration-not-working-for-visited-state-link)

You can done with this jquery `addClass`.

**Demo code**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('visited');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.visited {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/7y2fyytw/

Comment: This is great, however ideally it would be persistent on page reload the way normal visited links work. Reloading the page would remove all the visited classes from visited links.

Answer (score -2):

Right now i have 2 theories with this.

1. The link you put there is not a link it is a file path. However, i tried to load this pic where its located at the pexels.com server [cat pic](https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg) . The `:visited` psuedo is working fine.
2. The second one is Your link is not active or not exist/ not the
   correct one. Because when i tried this its working

```css
a:link {
color: #222;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
    http://example.com
</a>

<br>
<br>
<a href="http://google.com">
    Google
</a>
```

Maybe if you provide the proper and working links, its working perfectly.

Comment: I already know why this is happening. CSS doesn't apply `:visited` to file paths. My question is pretty clear that I am linking to a file. The file does exist and the issue is simple to replicate. What I need is a solution so that I can style visited file URLs.

Comment: Well then, do you want me to edit my answer using jquery to change link color when clicked? it can be permanent until you refresh tho.

Comment: When the user clicks the link, the user isn't on the page anymore.

Comment: use target="_blank"..  what is your purpose exactly?? Do you really have issue or not?